# Where can I get public beta ipsw files for iOS?

Tags: ios, beta-seed-program, ipsw

I tried it via OTA but it failed (stuck at 95% for two hours), so I'm going to reinstall iOS.

Because I have to reinstall iOS via Mac anyways, I would like it if I could install beta version in the first place instead of installing 12.4, updating it via OTA.

However, I can't find official link for ipsw files for public beta.

Am I missing something or does Apple not provide ipsw files for public beta? (I know there's developer version ipsws, but I'm looking for public beta ipsw files)

Comment: Check https://ipsw.me/

Comment: Try this [link](https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/)